# "Wire" multiple Deployments to one Service in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have several different Deployments.
`Deployment A: export port 3333`
`Deployment B: export port 4444`
I want to use a single Service(with LoadBalancer type) to export them.
`Service Main: export port 4545 -> Route to Deployment A's port 3333
               export port 5555 -> Route to Deployment B's port 4444`

The documentation say that you can export multiple ports on one services, but it doesn't say whether it works for multiple Deployments.
Since Services use `selector` to select Deployments but in my case, there will be more than one Deployment comes from the selecting result.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that is possible today, but it seems like a potentially useful feature. I filed a [feature request](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24875).